# What low-cost ultra-wide angle DX lens will autofocus on my Nikon D5000?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, autofocus, wide-angle

I need a wide angle lens for low-light/club photography with my Nikon D5000.  I was going to pick up [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0014Z3XMC), but then I realized that it won't autofocus on my body.  What is the closest equivalent in terms of price and performance that will?

Comment: Bear in mind that AF doesn't work very well in low light situations anyway - might open up a few more choices if you just go manual.

Answer (score 4):

If you can try it out before buying, the Tokina 11-16 might still be the best option. It is less expensive than the Nikon 12-24. The Nikon is the runner up in my opinion. The two lenses are significantly different: the Nikon 12-24 is part of the 3 lens continuous zoom coverage set, the Tokina 11-16 is a Prime with wiggle room.

I say that the Tokina might be your best option since focus does not have to be very precise. The focus scale is 1/4 turn on this lens, it goes from 1ft to infinity. 2ft is over halfway across the scale. Another consideration is whether auto-focus will be effective in a club environment. It is probable that neither the Tokina or Nikon will auto-focus in a club without the af assist light on-- and that is so bright you will annoy people and disrupt your composition.

Answer (score 3):

I own the Tokina 11-16.  It's a great lens, but you'd be surpirised how wide the lens is.  I use it on a D7000.  Also, the limited zoom range (it's really wide even at the 16mm setting.)  Unless you're literally a meter in front of the subject, it's going to look small.

Also - it's so wide, your flash won't light the whole frame.

I am looking to solve a similar problem to what you have - and I'm currently planning on purchasing the Nikon 17-55mm lens as the solution to the problem.

I've been testing the concept - standing at the back of the room with my 80-200mm 2.8 on my D7000, ISO at about 3000 and shooting around 1/60 - 1/100 sec.  With Aperture at 2.8.

No flash - using the stage lighting only - it produces a fairly decent image.  You can see the grain, but it's acceptable if you frame your shot well and don't have to zoom in too much.

Answer (score 2):

Tokina apparently makes a D5000 compatible version of your original lens.

[http://www.amazon.com/Tokina-11-16mm-AT-X116-Digital-Cameras/dp/B007ORX8ME/ref=pd_cp_p_0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007ORX8ME)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an AF-S lens.  Unfortunately most of the lenses available will be more expensive or have a smaller maximum aperture.

- [Nikon 12-24mm f/4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000092M1T)
- [Nikon 17-35mm f/2.8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005LEOS)
- [Nikon 17-55mm f/2.8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000144I2Q)
- [Sigma 10-20mm f/3.5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002D2VSD6)

I think the Sigma is probably the closest in price/performance to the Tokina.

Comment: The Tokina is an excellent performer while the Sigma you mention here is not. The closest would be the Nikkor 12-24mm F/4, only a tad narrower and one stop less bright. It is very sharp from wide open though.

Comment: Whatabout this lense?  I would be worried about the relatively low maximum aperture, but the wide angel can't be beat and it's relatively inexpensive on Amazon.

[link](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/689635-REG/Sigma_203101_8_16mm_F4_5_5_6_DC_HSM.html) Sigma 8-16

Comment: @Itai, yes, I own the 12-24mm, great lens, but it's a much more expensive lens. Very subjective this relative price/performance stuff :)